# How to use Python Pillow's Transpose.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, deprecated

I am using **Pillow 9.1.0** to flip an image upside-down.

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('example.png')
flipped = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
```

Recently a warning shown up:

```
DeprecationWarning: FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Transpose.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM instead.
  flipped = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
```

I tried to import Transpose from PIL but it did not work.

```py
from PIL import Image, Transpose
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, Transpose
ImportError: cannot import name 'Transpose' from 'PIL' (.../site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

How to import and use `Transpose.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM` properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all written in the [deprecation document](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deprecations.html). Instead of `Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM`, you should be using `Image.Transpose.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM`.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot save flipped image.
Try to add codeline below.

```
flipped.save()
```

So, finally your code must be like that:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('example.png')
flipped = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
flipped.save('example.png')
```